# Implement UDP with TCP features

Tags: python, tcp, udp

I'm not sure where to even start, so far I have this for the server side:

```
 # Server program
 from socket import *
 import time
 import sys

 serverhost = '127.0.0.1'
 serverport = 5005
 buffersize = 2048

 serversock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)

 serveraddr = (serverhost, serverport)
 serversock.bind(serveraddr)
 print 'Server is ready to receive'

 while True:
    try:
            message, clientaddr = serversock.recvfrom(buffersize)
            print 'Server received ', message, 'from ', str(clientaddr)


            print "Server sending back " + str(message)
            serversock.sendto(message, clientaddr)

    except:
            print 'Exception occured, closing socket'
            break

   serversock.close()
```

and this for the client side:

```
   # Client program
   from socket import *
   import time
   import sys
   import struct

   def Main():

    srcip = destip = "127.0.0.1"
    srcport, destport = 5005, 5000
    payload = '[TESTING]\n'

    tcp = make_tcp(srcport, destport, payload)
    packet = tcp + payload

    buffersize = 2048
    addr = (destport, serverport)
    clientsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)

    def tcp(srcport,destport, payload, seq=123 , ackseq=0,
                 fin=False, syn=True, rst=False, psh=False, ack=False, urg=False,
                 window = 5840):
            offsetres = (5 << 4) | 0
            flags = (fin | (syn << 1) | (rst << 2) |
                     (psh << 3) | (ack << 4) | (urg << 5))
            return struct.pack('HHLLBBHHH',
                               srcport, destport, seq, ackseq, offset_res,
                               flags, window, 0, 0)

    data = "This is the client"

    try:
            start = time.time()

            clientsock.sendto(data, packet, serveraddr, (destip, 0))
            print "Client sent message ...", data, "... waiting for response."

            response, addr = clientsock.recvfrom(buffersize)
            response_id = struct.unpack('!HI', response[4:6])

            end = time.time()
            elapsed = end - start

            print response_id
            print "Elapsed time = ", elapsed

    except:
            print "Exception occured"


    clientsock.close()

    if __name__== "__main__":
        Main()
```

I'm not sure if the TCP header is correct so far, but How do I start a message exchange? It's supposed to be sending packets over UDP with TCP features. How should I start the connection (three way handshake)?

Comment: Why not just use TCP?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. There's a big difference between a UDP packet header and a TCP packet header. Additionally, you can't specify the UDP protocol number - 17 for IPv4 - in an IP packet header and then send a TCP packet over the wire - the receiving end expects something that looks like protcol 17 but is protocol 6 (TCP).

Are you looking to get the "speed" of UDP with the "safety" of TCP? You'd have to deal with the byzantine generals problem but you could make UDP (questionably) "safer" with your own UDP handshake.

Maybe you just want to send TCP packets over UDP?

Comment: @marklap - OP is trying to implement a TCP header over UDP. he doesn't expect it to interact with a standard TCP/IP socket, just one of his TCP/UDP/IP sockets. Its hard but doable.

Comment: @tdelaney ok... after looking closely at the code I can see what you're talking about. OP "simply" wants to send a TCP header as the payload of a UDP packet.